# How to force vaadin use WebSockets as transport not only for push

Tags: java, websocket, vaadin

I have button in my user interface and click event sent to the server through http request. I can't find in documentation any way to force vaadin use websocket for all actions in ui. Maybe not general there is no problem to configure each listener manually.

My UI exmple:

```
    @Theme("valo")
    @Title("System monitor")
    @Push(value = PushMode.AUTOMATIC, transport = Transport.WEBSOCKET)
    public class SystemMonitorUI extends UI {

       @Override
       protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
            Button refresh = new Button("refresh");
            refresh.addClickListener(clickEvent -> {
                time.setValue(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
            });         
            setContent(refresh);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Have you read this https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Working+around+push+issues and installed/configured what is required?

Comment: Is it possible to use just Websockets in a web app?